# Bisection Method of Transcendental equation

Tags: transcendental-equations, bisection

Find a root correct to $3$ decimal places and range is $0$ & $0.5$ 
$F(x) = 4e^{-x} \sin x -1.$

According to book I follow answer is provided as $0.371$ correct to $3$ dp. I am unable to arrive at this.

Also $f(0.25)$  is given as $-0.22929$ and this trans equation is giving me nightmares. Experts request your help.

Comment: Do you understand bisection? Where do you stuck?

Comment: @Moo how it's determined that 0.371is correct to 3dp. If you could explain it wd be a great help

Comment: @SureshKumar it is due to the bisection method. If you share your work, we would be able to help you more easily.

Comment: Let $f(x)=4\sin x -e^x.$ Use Newton's Method $x_{n+1}=x_n-f(x_n)/f'(x_n)$ with $x_1=0.$

Comment: @user254665: bisection was explicitly asked. And the newton method won't tell you the number of correct digits.

Comment: Newtons' method certainly can  give you a good estimate of the error.

Comment: @user254665: relative to the second derivative...